# Can a using statement appear in a constructor initialization list?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

How can one incorporate a `using` statement into a constructor initialization list?

For example, rather than

```
foo::foo(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(something_long::tada(c)) {}
```

I would like to have

```
// Invoking some 'using something_long::tada;' magic
foo::foo(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(tada(c)) {}
```

Presumably this looks something like the goofy try/catch syntax required in this code region.  Functionally, permiting using statements feels important as `something_long::tada(c)` and `using something_long::tada; tada(c)` can have different behavior per Koenig lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Would a namespace alias help?

```
using SVLI = something::very::long::indeed;

foo::foo(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(SVLI::tada(c)) {}
```

Comment: That surmounts my length complaint, say when I use `SVLI` repeatedly within a hypothetical `c1`, `c2`, `c3` all like `c` above, but it doesn't provide Koenig lookup.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many levels of namespaces you need to type. If you need to type quite a few levels of namespaces, you could bridge it in a static function:

```
class foo
{
  //...
  static int tada_again(int c)
  {
    return namespaceA::namespaceB::namespaceC::namespaceD::namespaceE::tada(c);
  }
  //...
};

foo::foo(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(tada_again(c))
{
}
```

If there aren't many levels of namespaces need to be typed, from maintain or code readability point of view, keep clear namespace will be better.

Comment: That provides the brevity within the constructor but it doesn't provide Koenig lookup.  One could add a `using namespaceA::namespaceB::etc;` line above the `tada(c)` bit to accomplish what I'm after.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As a Very Gross Hack, one thing you could do would be to have two separate implementation files.  One of the implementation files would be a normal implementation file in which you'd implement everything *except* the constructor.  In the second implementation file, you'd do

```
#include "appropriate-header-file"
using namespace something_long;

foo::foo(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(tada(c)) {};
```

That way, when compiling the constructor, the compiler will have the `using` declaration to make `tada` shorter.  However, this doesn't pollute the namespace in the standard implementation file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe wrap `something_long::tada(c)` in a new function? like static private function.

Comment: Clever, but I'm not sure the extra effort of creating a separate header file really beats out having to type out a namespace.

Comment: @Yuushi- This is just a proof of concept that shows that in principle it is possible to do this.  Though I completely agree!

Comment: Eewww..  That's a Very Gross Hack, but it does turn out that I can do something similar in my code that's Not Quite So Gross.  Thank you.